# Unity and dynamic WCF proxies

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container, soa

Is there any way to have unity inject the proxies to WCF services dynamically at runtime? Specifically, I'd like to be able to do a Resolve call on the ServiceContract interface and have it look to the unity config for a service URL, dynamically build the proxy (easy enough with codedom) and have it cache (singleton?) that proxy for future calls. I've found plenty of samples to inject a pre-referenced client proxy, and plenty of dynamic proxy implementations, but nothing that seems to close the gap.. Has anyone does this? Any sample code I can glance at?

Comment: Maybe this would help bridge the gap: http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/RegisteringFactoryMethodCreateObjectsUnityStaticFactoryExtension.aspx - Not sure the lifestyle of these objects though.  At worst, you could use traditional methods to make it a singleton (static property on a class).

Comment: If I'm understanding your suggestion right, I would build a static class that dynamically generates/returns the proxy and register it this way? If so, how do I ensure the lifetime of the singleton?

Specifcally, lets say I have WCF service A, wherein i use this to inject a second service B. How would this translate across two calls to service A? Would each one then build the proxy the first time around? Any way to make it 'shared' across multiple calls/clients to A?

Comment: Not sure.  I think the process still hangs around, so static data would too.  But I'm just throwing out ideas here.  If you said that registering it as a Singleton within the container is the best way to go, I would agree with you.  Tho that doesn't sound like it would solve your problem either - your problem sounds like a separate issue: How to make a container or singleton live across requests.  Also, it seems weird to me that two services would be on separate boxes/assemblies.  If they aren't, it would make more sense to inject the service itself rather than any proxy.